# getting custom org-agenda to filter out entries

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to write my first custom org-agenda. I want to see only items that are tagged "@project" and have a state of TODO, NEXT, or WORKING--all schedule for within the next 7 days. I wrote the code below, but it still include all the other items from the GLOBAL TODOs for the next 7 days.

I have this code so far.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "Weekly Work Projects"
         ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 7)))
          (todo "@project")
          (todo "NEXT") 
          (todo "TODO")
      (todo "WORKING")))  
        ))
```

I think the problem is associated with the line:

```
 (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 7)))
```

This line creates a 7 day GLOBAL TODOs list. However I was not sure how to only select items that have an @project tag and are also in the NEXT|TODO|WORKING states *over the next 7 days.*

Anyone have an idea of how to correct this.

Comment: `org-agenda-ndays` was declared obsolete at some point, so you may have to use `org-agenda-span` instead, depending on the version of Org-mode you are using. N.B. this is not a complete answer, which is why it's a comment (for now).

Comment: Oh interesting @Nick, I had not seen `org-agenda-span` before. All of the examples I looked at used `org-agenda-ndays.` I will give it a shot thought. Thanks for your help. Yeah, I have been making some slow progress on this issue, haha.